# Odoo 8 : Personalized error message after trying to modify a read-only object

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

In Odoo 8, I added an `ir.rule` to a model that restricts write access for certain users. I would like to personalize the error message restricted user get after clicking 'Save'. I can't just modify the translation with `_()` because the new message must be specific to that model.

Is there a way to do this easily in Odoo 8 without having to modify the source code of Odoo itself ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `Save` button invokes the model's `write` method. In that case, you can override this method to raise custom error message when the corresponding conditions are met. You have the `uid` of the user that called the `write` method, so it must be enough to achieve the desired effect.